# Multiply 2 textbox values and display in 3rd textbox

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to multiply 2 numbers ( one in each textbox) and display in another textbox
When I enter the numbers, nothing happens.
textBox8 displays "2.50", and textBox 10 displays "5".

```
private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Multiply();
        }

        private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Multiply();
        }

        public void Multiply()
        {
            int a, b;

            bool isAValid = int.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out a);
            bool isBValid = int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out b);

            if (isAValid && isBValid)
                textBox7.Text = (a * b).ToString();

            else
                textBox7.Text = "Invalid input";
        }
```

Comment: Did you hook the two events handler to the event in the View?

Comment: I see "Invalid Input"

Comment: @user3237403 On which line exactly? What are the values of `textBox8.Text` and `textBox8.Text`?

Comment: I mean I see "Invalid input" displayed in textBox7, and whatever I type.

Comment: Well its working for me, can you attach a screenshot

Comment: @user3237403 Oh `:)` If one of your `int.TryParse` method returns `false`, it is obviously your `else` part work, not `if` part.

Comment: are you sure you are entering the values that can be parsed to int?

Comment: You need to enter both values correctly to see the output

Comment: If I use your code all will work on my machine. What are your input values?

Comment: The numbers in textBox8 are (for example) 2.50, and textBox 10 is 2.

Comment: @user3237403 `2.50` ? do you think it's an integer ?

Comment: In that case your problem is in the input. You're trying to convert a float to an int.

Comment: Uh, that's the problem 2.50 is not an integer

Comment: What is the solution?

Comment: You are using a decimal or double numeric type not an integer. Use the proper TryParse method

Comment: Use integers values as input.

Comment: Add the `trim()` function call with text

Comment: double.TryParse() or float.TryParse() or decimal.TryParse()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`The numbers in textBox8 are (for example) 2.50, and textBox 10 is 2`

`2.50` is a decimal value and cannot be parsed to `int`

change `int.TryParse` to `decimal.TryParse`

```
 int a, b;

 bool isAValid = int.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out a);
 bool isBValid = int.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out b);
```

to

```
 decimal a, b;

 bool isAValid = decimal.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);
 bool isBValid = decimal.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out b);
```

Comment: why -1? will someone explain?

Comment: This works perfect, double and float display "5" where as decimal displays "5.00" which is what I need.

Comment: The two decimals is just an artifact of the ToString() operation with a decimal. If you try ToString("N") with double or float you get the same output as with decimal

Answer (score 0):

Use `double.TryParse`

```
double a, b;

bool isAValid = double.TryParse(textBox8.Text.Trim(), out a);
bool isBValid = double.TryParse(textBox10.Text.Trim(), out b);

if (isAValid && isBValid)
    textBox7.Text = (a * b).ToString();

else
    textBox7.Text = "Invalid input";
```

Answer (score 0):

> The numbers in textBox8 are (for example) 2.50, and textBox 10 is 2.

[`Int32.TryParse(String s, out int)` overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) uses [`NumberStyle.Integer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. That's why your `2.50` fails and `isAValid` will be `false`. With `NumberStyle.Integer`, your strings can have only;

- Leading white space.
- Trailing white space.
- Leading positive or negative sign.

That's why `isAValid && isBValid` will be `false` (regardless what `isBValid` is) and your *else statement* works.

As a solution, you can use [`Double.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which it uses `NumberStyles.Float| NumberStyles.AllowThousands` with `CurrentCulture` like;

```
double a;
bool isAValid = Double.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out a);
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
    private void textBox8_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply();
    }

    private void textBox10_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Multiply();
    }

    public void Multiply()
    {
        float a, b;

        bool isAValid = float.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out a);
        bool isBValid = float.TryParse(textBox10.Text, out b);

        if (isAValid && isBValid)
            textBox7.Text = (a * b).ToString();
        else
            textBox7.Text = "Invalid input";
    }
```

of course, as mentioned by the other answer, you can use decimal or double, it all depends on the precision you want:
**float**: single-precision floating point (32 bit).
**double**: double precision floating point (64 bit).
**decimal**: 128-bit floating point.

Best regards!

Comment: Well, are you talking about 2 decimal numbers like 1.00?
In that case your problem lies in .ToString() and not in float or double. Using (a * b).ToString("N") or string.Format("{0:0.00}", (a * b)); will do the exact same thing, with even more control over your output. I think that using an 128-bit variable should be used in cases where large decimals are really important like in monetary transactions. Otherwise, if you are using smaller numbers, stick to float or double.